# How to validate an XSL without getting an StackOverflowException when running inside IIS?

Tags: xml, validation, xslt

I have the following code that validates an incoming xsl:

```
string xsl = ...;
try
{
    var xslTransform = new XslCompiledTransform();
    using (var stream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(xsl)))
    {
        using (var reader = XmlReader.Create(stream))
        {
            xslTransform.Load(reader, new XsltSettings(false, true), new XmlUrlResolver());
        }
    }
}
catch (XsltException ex)
{
    // Validation failed
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    // Unexpected failure
}
```

Unfortunately, for some XSL documents the code raises an `StackOverflowException` **when ran from within an ASP.NET request in IIS**.

The obvious solution is to raise the bar by increasing the stack size, but it is not a real solution - Murphy law dictates that it will be reproduced and at the least convenient moment.

So, I am looking for another solution. Suggesting other XML/XSL frameworks is also welcome.

You can find an example XSL here - http://pastebin.com/KWfrFYCW

**EDIT 1**

Unfortunately, we are not in much control of the XSL documents - they are created by the clients.

**EDIT 2**

Interesting, the obsolete `XslTransform` does not throw SOE, however, the real XSL contains a little bit of C# code, so I really need the **enable script** validation option provided in the `XsltSettings` object, which does not seem to be supported by `XslTransform`

**EDIT 3**

As [Trying to use XslTransform to validate an XSL with a script fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34230610/trying-to-use-xsltransform-to-validate-an-xsl-with-a-script-fails) shows `XslTransform` does not support the `msxsl:using` tag, which is in use by our clients. Unfortunately, I cannot tell each and every client to go over their XSL files and rewrite them without `msxsl:using`. Hence I cannot use `XslTransform`.

**EDIT 4**

The Saxon EE seems to work fine. Here is the code:

```
var processor = new Processor();
processor.NewXsltCompiler().Compile(new FileStream(XSL_PATH, FileMode.Open));
```

Given an XSL with both the `msxsl:script` and `msxsl:using` tags no exception is thrown. I suppose it means that Saxon EE does understand those, doesn't it?

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/xmlteam/archive/2011/09/26/effective-xml-part-5-something-went-really-wrong-outofmemoryexception-and-stackoverflowexception-thrown-when-using-xslcompiledtransform.aspx has some suggestions.

Comment: @MartinHonnen - see **EDIT 1**. Alas, there will be bad XSL documents. Still, I do not like to see my process killed, because of them.

Comment: Wow this is some of the ugliest abuse of XSLT that I have ever seen. Telling your clients to get their act together would be a good start. ;)

Comment: In the .NET framework there are alternatives, Microsoft's own `XslTransform` is deemed obsolete by `XslCompiledTransform` but I don't think it will be removed, so you could try whether it works better with your stylesheets. Then there is the .NET version of Saxon 9, available in an open source version from http://saxon.sourceforge.net/ and in commercial editions from http://www.saxonica.com/, it is an XSLT 2.0 processor.

Comment: Another XSLT 2.0 processor is XmlPrime, you would need to get in touch with them at http://www.xmlprime.com/, I am not sure whether they have solely decided not to offer an up to date trial version or whether they don't want to to sell they processor any longer.

Comment: @MartinHonnen - please, see **EDIT 2**

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xsl.xsltransform%28v=vs.110%29.aspx supports `ms:script` as far as I remember and as far as the documentation says.

Comment: @MartinHonnen - I cannot make it work with a script - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34230610/trying-to-use-xsltransform-to-validate-an-xsl-with-a-script-fails

Comment: @MartinHonnen - please, see **EDIT 3**

Comment: @MartinHonnen - Saxon seems to be a good direction. Would you like to arrange your comment as an answer so I could credit you?

Comment: @mark, as far as I know Saxon has no support for inline C# code, at least not in a way directly compatible with the `ms:script/ms:using` elements you made an requirement, so I am now a bit astonished that you say it looks like an option for you.

Comment: @MartinHonnen - please, see **EDIT 4**. Granted, I haven't tried to actually perform the transformation - just compile the XSL, but I assume if it did not support the `ms:script/ms:using` it would have thrown an exception. I am using the Enterprise Edition, BTW.

Comment: The possible extension mechanisms of Saxon are documented at http://saxonica.com/html/documentation/extensibility/. As for `ms:script`, no, the specification allows top-level elements in non XSLT namespace, and a processor is simply asked to ignore them if the namespace is not known, see http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#dt-data-element, which says "Thus, an implementation is always free to ignore user-defined data elements, and must ignore such data elements without giving an error if it does not recognize the namespace URI.".

Comment: Hmm, so you are saying it does not recognize the script part and just ignores it? That is a bummer. At this moment I am kind of perplexed as to my next steps. I will try XmlPrime.

Comment: @MartinHonnen - you are absolutely right. I have used the simple XSL/XML you have provided in your answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34230610/trying-to-use-xsltransform-to-validate-an-xsl-with-a-script-fails and Saxon fails to transform it. `XslCompiledTransform` does it alright. Please, arrange of all your comments as a reply to my question. You have provided a wealth of very useful information and even if it does not answer my question to my satisfaction it is still very valuable and deserves up voting.

Comment: @MartinHonnen - Checked XmlPrime. It supports the scripts, but throws SOE just the same as `XslCompiledTransform`.